# With jQuery UI, how can I check if the tooltip has been enabled or disabled for an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

Using jQuery UI, I know you can enable tooltips for all elements that have the same class like this:

```
$('.someClass').tooltip('enable');
```

and disable them like this:

```
$('.someClass').tooltip('disable');
```

How can I check the current state of the tooltips for the 'someClass' elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$( ".someClass" ).tooltip( "option", "disabled" );`